# How do I check if the enter key has been pressed in a Scanner?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, enter

First, I tried:

```
while (!(in.nextLine().equals("")))
    arrayList.add(in.nextInt());
```

This doesn't work out too well at all for me. Instead, I tried:

```
while (in.hasNextint())
    arrayList.add(in.nextInt());
```

Basically I type numbers separated by whitespace and then enter some letter and press enter. This works perfectly in IDEs. However, if I try to compile and run it using the command prompt it throws an error in my face: InputMismatchException. Finally, I tried:

```
while (in.nextLine() != null) 
    arrayList.add(in.nextInt());
```

And that did not work(!) Any ideas?

Comment: What line does this exception occure on? Could we see a complete (small) program to show this. And the input you feed to this program

Comment: Plus obligatory mention as to [ommiting braces being a bad idea](http://cafe.elharo.com/blogroll/braceless-if-considered-harmful/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For keyboard, you would need a

```
keyListener
```

You can do this in the class void
(I mean the void the same name as your class) For example:

```
public Classname(){
    //stuff
    window.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
//For every time the specific key is being pressed
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
            KeyCode = e.getKeyCode();
                switch (KeyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE: 
                    //stuff
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_H:
                    //stuff
                    break;

                }
            }
        }
//For every time the specific key is being released
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
            switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT: //stuff
 break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT: //stuff
   break;

        }
    });

}
```

Also, I think there's a public

```
keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
```

void that you can use.

Hope this solves ur problem if it doesn't let me know by commenting. :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check this. If you read from a file or terminal, the "enter key will have been pressed" (at least metaphorically), otherwise your Scanner gets no input and will wait for it. If, OTOH, you create the Scanner on a String or something like that, that String is the input, and that's it. No key-pressing will change anythig here.